# Ubuntu 22.10 Kinetic can't update archive.ubuntu.com and ignored it

Tags: apt, server

I've got some problems. It appears today, yesterday was OK. What's going on? And what should I do? I just wanted update Ubuntu with `sudo apt update`

```
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security InRelease
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have the internet. My VM installed on Proxmox, and it worked yesterday.

My netplan is:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens18:
      dhcp4: no:( And m
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.122.205/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.122.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd`
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your paste, your issue is network related, so check your network configuration, filtering at your location.  Is your connection UP, do you have network address? have a router/access-point address?  does it respond to ping (*ICMP echo request*), can you ping external using IP address (eg. google via 8.8.8.8), can you ping external using a human address (ie. DNS) etc.

Comment: I've answered you, updated my message

Answer (score 15):

[Ubuntu 22.10 is not supported anymore](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) and `archive.ubuntu.com` does not offer packages for this release any longer. Follow the [upgrade documentation of Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades#Upgrading) to get to a current release.

In my case, in `/etc/apt/sources.list` I replaced the `*.archive.ubuntu.com` source with `old-releases.ubuntu.com` to get updates working again:

```
sudo sed -i 's|http://\([a-z0-9.-]*\)\.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu|http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu|' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

After that, it's prudent to update to the newer release:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: I found this reference that should help: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades#Upgrading

Comment: thanks @fp007 I updated my answer with that link.

Comment: An easier approach for newbies without using the command line:

    Open Software Updater >
    Settings >
    Ubuntu Software >
    Download from: >
    Other... >
    mirrors.ubuntu.com (scroll up to the first entry) >
    Choose Server >
    (Enter your password if prompted) >
    Close >
    Reload (when prompted about "software out-of-date")

Updating should work normally.

Comment: `An upgrade from 'kinetic' to 'mantic' is not supported with this 
tool.` Ubuntu finest